# Не удаляется класс

Tags: javascript

```js
var div = document.querySelector('.div');
var span = document.querySelectorAll('span');
div.addEventListener('click', function(e){
 var d = e.target;
 if(d.classList.contains('d')){
    d.classList.remove('d');
 }
  d.classList.add('d');
});
```

```css
.div{
  text-align: center;
 margin-top: 25%;
 font-size: 50px;
}
.d{
  color:red;
```

```html
<div class="div">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что вы написали удаление класса, если `if(d.classList.contains('d'))`... а сразу после удаления, сверху всё равно спокойно добавляется класс `d.classList.add('d')`. Как минимум, его надо поставить под else:

```js
var div = document.querySelector('.div');
div.addEventListener('click', function(e){
 var d = e.target;
 if(d.classList.contains('d')){
   d.classList.remove('d');
 } else { 
   d.classList.add('d'); 
 }
});
```

```css
.div{
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 50px;
  user-select: none;
}
.d {
  color:red;
}
span { margin: 5px; border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<div class="div">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>
</div>
```

Но всё равно есть ошибка - если кликнуть на сам блок между спанами - покрасятся все. Поэтому можно бы сразу к спанам всё привязать (а toggle позволяет не писать лишнего условия):

```js
var div = document.querySelector('.div');

div.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if( e.target.matches("span") ){
    e.target.classList.toggle('d');
  }
});
```

```css
.div{
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 50px;
  user-select: none;
}
.d {
  color:red;
}
span { margin: 5px; border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<div class="div">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>
</div>
```